# has_many and a legacy scheme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm looking for advice here:

I have two tables in legacy scheme, `A` and `B`, joined on `A.somename = B.othername`. Both of those columns are strings. So how do I set up relations between them in rails (v2.1.0)? Given that `A` has many `B`'s, what would be the best practice:

1. use `:finder_sql` and just write a SQL select,
2. configure the relation through other parameters (how? I know I can set `:foreign_key = 'othername'`, but that will just try to set up a `A.id = B.othername` relation - what can I do to set up the correct one?),
3. something else that has not crossed my mind.

So, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck with Rails 2.1 for some reason, the best option seems to be using `set_primary_key`, like this:

```
class A
  set_primary_key 'somename'
  has_many :bs, :foreign_key => 'othername'
end
```

There is also an alias that lets you use attribution-like syntax for that (`self.primary_key = 'somename'`).

By the way, if you're able to upgrade to 2.3, you can use the `primary_key` option directly with `has_many`, like this:

```
has_many :debitos, :primary_key => 'somename', :foreign_key => 'othername'
```

If you choose to use this, you won't need to declare the primary key for the class using `set_primary_key`.

Comment: Thank you - the second example is what I was trying to unsuccessfully find in the 2.1 API docs :) Sadly, upgrade to 2.3, while planned, is not an option right now. However, I found out that this works in 2.1:

    Class A
      set_primary_key :somename
      has_many :bs, :foreign_key => 'othername'
    end

Comment: Answer edited to include Toms' own findings. I think this version will be more useful for future users